# gsconfig installation in windows 7

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-css-module

[image]How do I install gsconfig in windows 7? I tried with gsconfig.tar.gz but the error is ImportError: No module named setuptools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to install gsconfig is via PIP, (PIP is used to install Python modules)

To install PIP, go here

http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html

Save the get-pip.py script and then install PIP by running

python get-pip.py

This will install PIP.

You can then install gsconfig using PIP

pip install gsconfig

as documented on the boundless github page found here - https://github.com/boundlessgeo/gsconfig

If PIP is not found you can either add C:\Python27\Scripts to your PATH environment variable or otherwise you will need to type the full path to PIP C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe